# JwtConsumer in multithreaded system

Tags: jwt, jose4j

I just want to clarify is **JwtConsumer** thread safe?
I'm going to use it with *spring rest controller*. Is it fine to use one consumer in whole application for multiple requests or better place it under request skope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, JwtConsumer is thread safe as long as you are using a recent version and, if your using any additional validators or customizers, they are also thread safe.

There was previously an [issue with thread safety](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/issues/25/reusability-and-thread-safety-of) but it was fixed in [v0.4.3](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Release%20Notes#!jose4j-043-june-19-2015).

Comment: Perhaps its worthy to add some javadoc to it, btw thank you very much)

Comment: I did actually add a bit about thread safety to the javadoc as a result of this question: https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/commits/22c9ea6fc4314daf80735dd8721f5ee331772cc0